# Phonegap - clear cache in ios app

Tags: ios, cordova, clear-cache

In my phonegap app, I have a feature to download new JS and HTML files and update into www folder. After updating, I need to clear old cached js & html files (without killing app and relaunching). In Android, I call DroidGap.appView.clearCache(true) to do this. But I did not find any similar method in iOS. I tried several ways:

Delete shared cache

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Clear cache of ASIHTTPRequest (I use this lib)

```
[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] clearCachedResponsesForStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
```

But none of them can resolve this problem. Anyone can help me? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: did u find a solution ?

Comment: @MohamedEmaish Hey, did you find a solution?

Comment: i don't remember at all , sorry :(